# Trying to load an hdf5 table with dataframe.to_hdf before I die of old age

Tags: pandas, hdf5, pytables

This sounds like it should be REALLY easy to answer with Google but I'm finding it impossible to answer the majority of my nontrivial pandas/pytables questions this way. All I'm trying to do is to load about 3 billion records from about 6000 different CSV files into a single table in a single HDF5 file. It's a simple table, 26 fields, mixture of strings, floats and ints. I'm loading the CSVs with `df = pandas.read_csv()` and appending them to my hdf5 file with `df.to_hdf()`. I really don't want to use `df.to_hdf(data_columns = True)` because it looks like that will take about 20 days versus about 4 days for `df.to_hdf(data_columns = False)`. But apparently when you use `df.to_hdf(data_columns = False)` you end up with some pile of junk that you can't even recover the table structure from (or so it appears to my uneducated eye). Only the columns that were identified in the min_itemsize list (the 4 string columns) are identifiable in the hdf5 table, the rest are being dumped by data type into `values_block_0` through `values_block_4`:

```
table = h5file.get_node('/tbl_main/table')
print(table.colnames)
['index', 'values_block_0', 'values_block_1', 'values_block_2', 'values_block_3', 'values_block_4', 'str_col1', 'str_col2', 'str_col3', 'str_col4']
```

And any query like `df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(table.read_where(condition))` fails with error "Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional"

So my questions are: (1) Do I really have to use `data_columns = True` which takes 5x as long? I was expecting to do a fast load and then index just a few columns after loading the table. (2) What exactly is this pile of garbage I get using `data_columns = False`? Is it good for anything if I need my table back with query-able columns? Is it good for anything at all?

Comment: Hey dts! This question is going to need quite a bit of editing before anyone can answer it. One of the cardinal rules is to ask 1 focused question at a time, so you'll probably get flagged for that. Also, showing a [mre] of the correct and garbled result, on some smallish dataframes, is going to help any readers figure out how to help.

Comment: I thought it was a generic question about data_columns = True versus False ... something that should be well-covered in the pytables documentation, but so far as I can tell is not.

Comment: Not sure why pytbales dos should cover this. `df.to_hdf(data_columns = True) ` versus `False` is a pandas function. If all your CSV files have the same columns of data, and all you want is HDF5 file of same, maybe you should skip pandas and use pytables or h5py instead. There are SO answers on how to do both.

Comment: Right, I stand corrected, should have said pandas documentation. I spent quite a bit of time looking at pytables to skip the dataframe read_csv step, but couldn't get the read_csv speed together with the richness of what read_csv can do while reading. But if pytables is way faster I would settle for just sucking the CSVs up with no fancy processing.

So, nobody knows anything about df.to_hdf(data_columns = True versus False)? One of life's great mysteries?

Comment: I was going to point you to my answer to a previous question about this. Then I discovered the "question was voluntarily removed by its author." I found my old code and modified to address your situation w/ multiple CSVs. See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can create an HDF5 file from CSV data using pytables. You could also use a similar process to create the HDF5 file with h5py.

1. Use a loop to read the CSV files with `np.genfromtxt` into a np array.
2. After reading the first CSV file, write the data with `.create_table()` method, referencing the np array created in Step 1.
3. For additional CSV files, write the data with `.append()` method, referencing the np array created in Step 1

End of loop
**Updated on 6/2/2019** to read a date field (mm/dd/YYY) and convert to `datetime` object. Note changes to `genfromtxt()` arguments! Data used is added below the updated code.

```
import numpy as np   
import tables as tb
from datetime import datetime
csv_list = ['SO_56387241_1.csv', 'SO_56387241_2.csv' ]

my_dtype= np.dtype([ ('a',int),('b','S20'),('c',float),('d',float),('e','S20') ])

with tb.open_file('SO_56387241.h5', mode='w') as h5f:

for  PATH_csv in csv_list:
    csv_data = np.genfromtxt(PATH_csv, names=True, dtype=my_dtype, delimiter=',', encoding=None)
    # modify date in fifth field 'e'   
    for row in csv_data :
        datetime_object = datetime.strptime(row['my_date'].decode('UTF-8'), '%m/%d/%Y' )
        row['my_date'] = datetime_object

    if h5f.__contains__('/CSV_Data') :
        dset = h5f.root.CSV_Data
        dset.append(csv_data)

    else:
        dset = h5f.create_table('/','CSV_Data', obj=csv_data)

    dset.flush()

h5f.close()
```

**Data for testing:**

```
SO_56387241_1.csv:
my_int,my_str,my_float,my_exp,my_date
0,zero,0.0,0.00E+00,01/01/1980
1,one,1.0,1.00E+00,02/01/1981
2,two,2.0,2.00E+00,03/01/1982
3,three,3.0,3.00E+00,04/01/1983
4,four,4.0,4.00E+00,05/01/1984
5,five,5.0,5.00E+00,06/01/1985
6,six,6.0,6.00E+00,07/01/1986
7,seven,7.0,7.00E+00,08/01/1987
8,eight,8.0,8.00E+00,09/01/1988
9,nine,9.0,9.00E+00,10/01/1989


SO_56387241_2.csv:
my_int,my_str,my_float,my_exp,my_date
10,ten,10.0,1.00E+01,01/01/1990
11,eleven,11.0,1.10E+01,02/01/1991
12,twelve,12.0,1.20E+01,03/01/1992
13,thirteen,13.0,1.30E+01,04/01/1993
14,fourteen,14.0,1.40E+01,04/01/1994
15,fifteen,15.0,1.50E+01,06/01/1995
16,sixteen,16.0,1.60E+01,07/01/1996
17,seventeen,17.0,1.70E+01,08/01/1997
18,eighteen,18.0,1.80E+01,09/01/1998
19,nineteen,19.0,1.90E+01,10/01/1999
```

Comment: This approach looks promising ... like maybe I can do everything I was doing with read_csv using genfromtxt instead, and it might have the speed I was expecting. But, being ignorant, I can't figure out how to read the string fields. And, I'm not allowed to enter enough characters here to show what I'm doing. Guess I will try to edit the original post above ...

Comment: Can't figure out how to add my code in edit ... what do I do, start a new question on the new topic "genfromtxt"?

Comment: Cancel that, the fourth time I tried the syntax like '|S10' it finally worked. Now I'm trying to figure out the string-to-int converters and date conversion ...

Comment: What do you mean by "can't figure out how to read the string fields"? When you use `dtype=None` , `genfromtxt` should auto-magically create the dtype based on the data it finds. Then `create_table` will use the np array dtype to define the table field datatypes. Also, remember that you are dealing with unicode objects. I don't know what happens if you have different length string fields on each row. Also, if you know the CSV file format, you can define the dtype and reference in `genfromtxt`.

Comment: I have to define the dtypes as a list, otherwise the "guesses" on the earlier CSVs will be the wrong sizes for the later CSVs. But even if I didn't need to do this, dtype = None gives garbage for the string fields. At the moment I'm giving up on all my converters and trying to live with none of those, except the dates.

Comment: Ok I actually  got all my converters working, except the dates. The data is 'mm/dd/yyyy' format and I think I want to convert to np.datetime64 (but I'll take anything I can get). I'm trying {'date': lambda s : np.datetime64(s, 's')} and a dozen variations on that, and other things Googled, but no love. Any hints?

Comment: Well, my project is still not off the ground, but it looks like kcw78's basic code will work to get something similar to the pandas version while retaining the speed ... so I will mark as answered. Final comment is, the 'w' flag won't work for me, I need 'a', otherwise the hdf5 file is recreated at every loop instead of appending.

Comment: The 'w' vs 'a' mode depends on order of opening the HDF5 file and reading the CSV files. I loop inside on the CSVs inside a `with` that creates/opens the HDF5 file. Different logic can result in different behavior.

Comment: Let's see if we can't fix your troubles with datetime. the Stating the obvious: The format of your dates depends on what you want to do with them. Strings are fine if you just want to print.  `datetime` expects string input, so handling depends on the datatype you got from `genfromtxt` . From my testing, the default return is a unicode. However you can define your dtype to read as strings. I modified the code in my answer to show one way you could do it. Also, I added the data used in the example. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the further input. I thought about the date conversion issue for a long time and decided it was best to convert to YYYYMMDD int32. These are columns that need to be indexed, and I don't like the python datetime type since I need cross-platform.

Comment: To convert datetime formats, check out `datetime strftime()`. You provide a datetime object and output format. Add `int()` if you need it. Add something like this to code above: `dt_ymd = int(datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime_object , '%Y%m%d'))`

Comment: That's helpful, but it assumes I've got a datetime object ... that was easy using pandas because I could use the infer_datetime_format and parse_dates arguments in the read_csv method, but I haven't yet figured out any way to do that under the hood with numpy.genfromtxt ... is there a way? The way I'm doing it now is using brute force with a custom converter that takes the byte string and does dt = datetime.strptime(byte_str.decode("UTF-8"), '%m/%d/%Y') ... probably very slow compared to pandas method.

Comment: dts, yeah, I was using the datetime object I created in my answer. I found an SO Q&A that reads datetime object by defining the `dtype` and adding `converters = {0:datefunc}` to `numpy.genfromtxt`. See this: [numpy-unicodedecodeerror-am-i-using-the-right-approach-with-genfromtxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36165426/)

Comment: That link has pretty much what I'm doing (converter). Actually it's working pretty well, I finished loading all my data into 2 big hdf5 files and it only took 4 days.

Comment: Good work. So, it's about as fast as `df.to_hdf(data_columns = False)` and way faster than `df.to_hdf(data_columns = True)`, and you finished before you die of old age. :-) Nice.

Comment: Correct ... and thanks very much for all your assistance, it was invaluable.